# hg clone Permission denied

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models
destination directory: gazebo_models
abort: Permission denied: gazebo_models

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2246/hg-clone-permission-denied/) by [benshaul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/294/benshaul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like you're running the `hg clone` command in a directory where you don't have permission to create files.  Try it in your home directory, e.g.:

```
cd $HOME
hg clone  https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benshaul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/294/benshaul/) on 2013-04-07**:
thanks....